# Java Catch Exception - Empty String

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm looking for an exception on how to catch an invalid String that is user input. I have the following code for a exception on an integer input:

```
            try {
            price = Integer.parseInt(priceField.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception) { 
            System.out.println("price error");
            priceField.setText("");
            break;
```

But I'm not aware of a specific exception for strings, the input is a simple JTextBox so the only incorrect input I can think of is if the user enters nothing into the box, which is what I'm looking to catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (textField.getText().isEmpty())
```

is all you need.

Or maybe

```
if (textField.getText().trim().isEmpty())
```

if you also want to test for blank inputs, containing only white spaces/tabs.

You generally don't use exceptions to test values. Testing if a string represents an integer is an exception to the rule, because there is no available `isInt()` method in String.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
if (priceField.getText().isEmpty()) 
  throw new Exception("priceField is not entered.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `priceField` contains a string by using this:

```
JTextField priceField;
int price;
try {
 // Check whether priceField.getText()'s length equals 0
 if(priceField.getText().getLength()==0) {
  throw new Exception();
 }
 // If not, check if it is a number and if so set price
 price = Integer.parseInt(priceField.getText());
} catch(Exception e) {
 // Either priceField's value's length equals 0 or
 // priceField's value is not a number

 // Output error, reset priceField and break the code
 System.err.println("Price error, is the field a number and not empty?");
 priceField.setText("");
 break;
}
```

When the if-statement is true (If the length of `priceField.getText()` is 0) an exception gets thrown, which will trigger the catch-block, give an error, reset `priceField` and `break` the code.

If the if-statement is false though (If the length of `priceField.getText()` is greater or lower than 0) it will check if `priceField.getText()` is a number and if so it sets `price` to that value. If it not a number, a NumberFormatException gets thrown, which will trigger the catch-block etc.

Let me know if it works.

Happy coding :) -Charlie

Answer (score 0):

if you want your exception to be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine, then you can use this

```
if (priceField.getText().isEmpty()) 
    throw new RunTimeException("priceField is not entered.");
```